# Python Vectorizing a Function Returning an Array

Tags: python, numpy, special-functions

I have the following function that has been vectorized so that for every element in input array t, an array is output:

```
@np.vectorize
def Ham(t):
    d=np.array([[np.cos(t),np.sqrt(t)],[0,1]],dtype=np.complex128)
    return d
```

I am getting an error: `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. I believe this error happens when there is conflicts with numpy and python, but I can't see where that would be. Also, if the dtype is not given, the error is `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` I'm guessing you can't assign arrays inside arrays in python, but how else can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `np.cos(t)` and `np.sqrt(t)` generate arrays with the length of `t`, whereas the second row (`[0,1]`) maintains the same size.
To use [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with your function, you have to define the output type, and [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) 
[isn't really meant as a decorator except for the simplest cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14986811/1771479).
In [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24925537/1771479) however you can generate the function with the right type:

```
def Ham(t):
    d=np.array([[np.cos(t),np.sqrt(t)],[0,1]],dtype=np.complex128)
    return d

HamVec = np.vectorize(Ham, otypes=[np.ndarray])
```

Now you can use `HamVec` as a function:

```
>>> x=np.array([1,2,3])
>>> HamVec(x)
array([ array([[ 0.54030231+0.j,  1.00000000+0.j],
       [ 0.00000000+0.j,  1.00000000+0.j]]),
       array([[-0.41614684+0.j,  1.41421356+0.j],
       [ 0.00000000+0.j,  1.00000000+0.j]]),
       array([[-0.98999250+0.j,  1.73205081+0.j],
       [ 0.00000000+0.j,  1.00000000+0.j]])], dtype=object)
```

---

Notes:

1. The [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)  [is just a convenience function, it doesn't actually make code run any faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379505/1771479).
2. This question might have been more suitable for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

---

**Edit:** as an answer to the follow up question: the resulting values of the matrix are of type `numpy.complex128`:

```
>>> y = HamVec(x)
>>> type(y[0][0][0])
<type 'numpy.complex128'>
```

And you can do for example:

```
>>> y*np.complex('3+2j')
array([ array([[ 1.62090692+1.08060461j,  3.00000000+2.j        ],
       [ 0.00000000+0.j        ,  3.00000000+2.j        ]]),
       array([[-1.24844051-0.83229367j,  4.24264069+2.82842712j],
       [ 0.00000000+0.j        ,  3.00000000+2.j        ]]),
       array([[-2.96997749-1.97998499j,  5.19615242+3.46410162j],
       [ 0.00000000+0.j        ,  3.00000000+2.j        ]])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! I just have another question though. Is there a way to change the output to be of type cfloat? I tried converting it inside the function, but it always returns an array of `dtype=object`

Comment: Are you sure this matters? The values in the result matrix are in fact of type `numpy.complex128`. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459017/how-to-convert-a-numpy-2d-array-with-object-dtype-to-a-regular-2d-array-of-float).

Comment: Hmm I thought the `dtype=object` meant that the result matrix was of object type. Is there a reason why it says that it is of type object and not complex128?

Comment: I have added an example to the answer.

Comment: Okay sorry if I keep asking questions here, but I am trying to take `numpy.linalg.eig` of the resulting matrix, but since there is `dtype=object` in the matrix, I get an error. Is there a simple way of removing dtype in the output array?